# What is a Java NullPointerException?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I created a Java Application and get this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at Executer.<init>(Executer.java:21)
    at Executer.main(Executer.java:14
```

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Executer {

private JLabel lblCommand;
private JTextField txtEnter;
private JButton btNext, btPrevious;
private JPanel panel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Executer();
}
public Executer() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Execute Script");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(900,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
    MyPanel();
    Text();
    Buttons();
    Fields();
}
public void MyPanel() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
}
public void Text(){
    lblCommand = new JLabel("Enter Here");
    lblCommand.setBounds(135, 50, 150, 20);
    Font styleOne = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13);
    lblCommand.setFont(styleOne);
    panel.add(lblCommand);
}

public void Fields () {
    txtEnter = new JTextField();
    txtEnter.setBounds(210, 50, 150, 20);
    panel.add(txtEnter);
}
public void Buttons() {
    btNext = new JButton ("Next");
    btNext.setBounds(380,325,100,20);
    panel.add(btNext);

    btPrevious = new JButton ("Previous");
    btPrevious.setBounds(260,325,100,20);
    panel.add(btPrevious);
}}
```

What is a NullPointerException?  How would I find out?

Comment: I don't know much about/care much for Swing applications, but I think that you have to instantiate `panel` in some way.  You pass it in as `null`.

Comment: To figure out the cause of a NPE, you should look at the stacktrace to find the first line that mentions a class and method from your own code. Starting from there work backwards to the last line that mentions a class and method from your code. This will give you a starting place to track down the cause of the problem.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: @EricLeschinski No, I don't think so. While knowledge of that may have helped, the problem here was simply that a line of code was placed in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 6):

You need to instantiate `panel` before adding it. If you use panel before calling `MyPanel()`, `panel` is still `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

While you're here, give this a glance. http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html

Method names in Java should be mixed case starting with a lower case letter, e.g. `myPanel()` instead of `MyPanel()`. To most of us, `MyPanel()` looks like a constructor at first glance because you improperly styled it.

Additionally, `MyPanel`, `Text`, `Fields`, and `Buttons` should all be private methods, as it would be improper for an external class to call them.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this line `frame.add(panel);` Panel is not initialized at that point, move this line `MyPanel();` before adding to initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to create the JPanel before you try to add it to the JFrame. In fact, you should typically create **all** components inside the JPanel as well. I suggest that you move the calls to

```
Text();
Buttons();
Fields();
```

from the `Executer` constructor to the `MyPanel()` method and call `MyPanel()` before calling `frame.add(panel);`.

In addition, you do not need to call `frame.setVisible(true);` twice. Also, you should use a `LayoutManager` rather than calling `panel.setLayout(null);`. See the Oracle tutorial for [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are adding panel to the frame before creating object of JPanel. Anyway change your constructor with this:

```
public Executer() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Execute Script");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(900, 400);

        MyPanel();
        Text();
        Buttons();
        Fields();

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

thanks.