# How to create star graph?

Tags: java, jgrapht

I am trying to create star graph using `JGraphT`, however what I have written seems to be wrong for compiler. What I get is a `NullPointerException` at lines marked as `NULL POINTER`. Why is that?

```
private static DefaultWeightedEdge edge(int i, int j) {
    DefaultWeightedEdge graphEdge = Graph.getEdge(i,j);
    return graphEdge;
}

private static int vertex(int i) {
    int vertex = VertexArray[i-1];
    return vertex;
}

private static void setWeight(DefaultWeightedEdge edge, double weight) {
    Graph.setEdgeWeight(edge, weight); //NULL POINTER
}


private static SimpleWeightedGraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge> createWeightedGraph() {
    Graph = new SimpleWeightedGraph<Integer, DefaultWeightedEdge>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        VertexArray[i] = i+1;
        Graph.addVertex(vertex(i+1));
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfEdges; i++) {
        DefaultWeightedEdge edge = Graph.addEdge(vertex(1), vertex(i+1)); 
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfEdges; i++) {
        setWeight(edge(1, i), 0.95);} //NULL POINTER

   //I would like to start group of threads here
    service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(manNum);
        for(int k=0; k < manNum; k++){
            ManufacturePattern manPat=new ManufacturePattern(k);
            service.submit(manPat);
        }

    return Graph;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `G.getEdge(i,j);` returns a value? PS: you should definitely work on your naming convention....

Comment: I think so. I used similar scheme in other program and it was working there. I'll edit the names ;)

Comment: (Edited) When there is an exception in the first line marked with `NULL POINTER`, then this simply means that your `Graph` is `null`. If the exception actually comes from *inside* the `setEdgeWeight` method, then most likely your `edge` is `null` because there is no edge `1,i` in the graph. In doubt, provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is there a reason for all that static hell? Without complete code, it is hard to tell what is causing Graph to be null.

Comment: Do you want to know [what a NullPointerException is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913640/what-is-a-java-nullpointerexception), or do you know but are wondering why? (Which I guess should be kind of clear if you know what it is.)

Comment: I found the mistake. I was using wrong data under `numberOfEdges`. Now it is all fine ;)